# For each char in string gives wrong result

Tags: c++, utf-8

There's a string that is in UTF-8 encoding, I can read it from a file and write it into another file just fine. But when I try to load each of the characters in that string one by one the result isn't coherent. I'm most likely doing this in a very wrong way, but what is the correct way to do this?

The content in `source.txt` is

```
afternoon_gb_1          ɑftənun
```

The code i wrote is

```
while (source >> word >> word_ipa) { 
for (char& c : word_ipa)
 myfile <<word<<" is " << c<< endl;}
```

The content in the txt file `myfile` gets written as

```
afternoon_gb_1 is �
afternoon_gb_1 is �
afternoon_gb_1 is f
afternoon_gb_1 is t
afternoon_gb_1 is �
afternoon_gb_1 is �
afternoon_gb_1 is n
afternoon_gb_1 is u
afternoon_gb_1 is n
```

Comment: I think you have an encoding issue, it's probably a unicode file so need to handle it as such.. could you load the file in a hex editor and show the result? xxd file on linux..  or could you upload a segment of the file somewhere so we can see it?

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying so quickly. I've uploaded the file in the question now.

Comment: This is fully expected. You need to read about utf-8 and understand how it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In UTF-8 each code-point (=logical character) is represented by multiple code units (=`char`); ɑftənun, in particular, is:

```
ch| c.p. | c.u.
--+------+-------
ɑ | 0251 | c9 91
f | 0066 | 66
t | 0074 | 74
ə | 0259 | c9 99
n | 006e | 6e
u | 0075 | 75
n | 006e | 6e
```

(ch=character; c.p.: code point number; c.p. code unit representation in UTF-8; c.u. and c.p. are expressed in hexadecimal)

The exact details of how the code points are mapped to the code units is explained [in many places](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Description); the very basics are that:

- code points less than 0x7f are mapped straight to a single code unit; for these, the high bit is never set;
- code points from 0x80 onwards are mapped to multiple code units; all the code units in a multi-code-unit sequence have the high bit set;
- if the high bit is set, the top bits have a particular meaning; in the first byte of a multibyte sequence they tell how many continuation bytes are to be expected, in the others they are unambiguously marked as continuation bytes.

If you print out each code unit on its own you are breaking the UTF-8 encoding for the code points that require more than one code unit to be expressed. Your terminal application in the first row sees

```
c9 0a
```

(the first code unit followed by a newline), and immediately detects that this is a broken UTF-8 sequence, as c9 has the high bit set but the next c.u. doesn't have it; hence the � character. The same holds for the second character, as well as for the c.u. parts of the sequence representing ə.

---

Now, if you want to print out full code-points (*not* code-units), `std::string` won't be of any help - `std::string` knows nothing about this stuff, it is essentially a glorified `std::vector<char>`, completely oblivious of encoding issues; all it does is to store/index *code units*, not code points.

There are however third party libraries to help work with this; [utf8-cpp](http://utfcpp.sourceforge.net/) is a small but complete one; in your case, the `utf8::next` function would be particularly helpful:

```
while (source >> word >> word_ipa) {
    auto cur = word_ipa.begin();
    auto end = word_ipa.end();
    auto next = cur;
    for(;cur!=end; cur=next) {
        utf8::next(next, end);
        myfile << word << "is ";
        for(; cur!=next; ++cur) myfile<<*cur;
        myfile << "\n";
    }
}
```

`utf8::next` here just increments the given iterator to make it point to the code point that starts the next code unit; this code makes sure that we print together all the code units that make up a single code point.

Notice that we can reproduce its barebones behavior quite simply, it's just a matter of reading the UTF-8 specs (see the first table in the link to Wikipedia above):

```
template<typename ItT>
void safe_advance(ItT &it, size_t n, ItT end) {
    size_t d = std::distance(it, end);
    if(n>d) throw std::logic_error("Truncated UTF-8 sequence");
    std::advance(it, n);
}


template<typename ItT>
void my_next(ItT &it, ItT end) {
    uint8_t b = *it;
    if(b>>7 == 0) safe_advance(it, 1, end);
    else if(b>>5 == 6) safe_advance(it, 2, end);
    else if(b>>4 == 14) safe_advance(it, 3, end);
    else if(b>>3 == 30) safe_advance(it, 4, end);
    else throw std::logic_error("Invalid UTF-8 sequence");
}
```

Here we are exploiting the fact that the first byte of a sequence declares how many extra code points are going to come to complete the code unit.

(notice that this expects valid UTF-8 and does not do any attempt to resynchronize a broken UTF-8 sequence; the library version probably fares way better in this regard)

OTOH, it's also possible to inline just what's necessary to keep the same code unit together:

```
while (source >> word >> word_ipa) {
    auto cur = word_ipa.begin();
    auto end = word_ipa.end();
    for(;cur!=end;) {
        myfile << word << "is "<<*cur;
        if(uint8_t(*cur++)>>7 != 0) {
            for(; cur!=end && (uint8_t(*cur)>>6)==2; ++cur) myfile<<*cur;
        }
        myfile << "\n";
    }
}
```

Here instead we are disregarding completely the "declared count" in the first c.u., we just check if the high bit is set; in this case, we go on printing as long as we get c.u. with the top two bytes set to 10 (in binary, AKA 2 in decimal) - since the "continuation c.u." of a multi-c.u. UTF-8 sequence all follow this pattern.

Comment: Fantastic answer, Matteo. Although presumably not your intention in this particular case, there is sufficient context and clarity here (without introducing unnecessary waffle) that this is actually the perfect good "canonical" answer.

Comment: Thank you, that's surely a comforting feedback, given the poor response I was wondering whether I missed completely the objective or I've been too handwavy in my exposition.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. And thank you so much for the detailed answer, it helped heaps! I was just wondering how should I link that external utf-8 library to my project