# How can char store two numbers?

Tags: c, char, cyrillic

The case in next: I have cyrillic symbol "б". Running next code:

```
int main() {
    char c;
    scanf("%c", &c);
    printf("%d\n", c);
    return 0;
}
```

Shows `-48`. BUT when i am debugging this variable `c`, it shows me next: `-48 '\320'`[image].

So how does this work? Is this a pointer to a 2-length array? Or how is it able to store two numbers?

Comment: Octal numbers strike again.

Comment: No c is a char and can only store 1 byte.

Comment: @Fredrik A `char` can store *at least* one byte.

Comment: @Broman No. A byte is a unit of memory, a `char` is a type, capable of representing a character from the implementation's basic character set.

Comment: @EOF I don't see how that contradicts what I said.

Comment: @Broman A `char` doesn't store *anything*. An *object* stores something, and so the correct way around would be to say that a byte can store *exactly* one `char`.

Comment: The debugger isn't showing two numbers. It's showing two representations of the same value, one in decimal and the other as a character with an escape sequence.

Comment: @EOF Ok, an object of type char can store at least one byte.

Comment: @Broman That sentence is meaningless.

Comment: @EOF Do you agree that 1 byte = 8 bits?

Comment: @Broman Of course not. `CHAR_BIT` is implementation-defined and must be equal **or larger** than 8.

Comment: @EOF I just found that in the documentation. Disregard everything I said.

Comment: @Broman: as far as the standard is concerned, `char` is pretty much the definition of a byte, however large it is. You two are mixing the two definitions - "byte = octet" (what is generally intended nowadays in general in the software community) and "byte = minimum addressable quantity = `char`" (what the C and C++ standards mean with byte).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `char` variable may either be used to store a small<sup>1</sup> integer, or a character (more properly, code unit) in some not-so-well-defined, generally-ASCII-based encoding. Here the debugger is just trying to be helpful by displaying two (disputably) meaningful representations of the content of `c`.

---

Let's imagine for a moment that you actually wrote `a` instead of `б`; in that case, the debugger would write something like

```
c = {char} 97 'a'
```

because the actual number stored in `c` is 97, and, decoded as ASCII, it corresponds to the letter `a`.

Unfortunately, the idea that you can fit every possible character in a single 8-bit `char` value is completely flawed, so the most widespread encoding used nowadays (UTF-8), which happens to be the one in use on your machine, requires multiple *code units* (≈bytes) to represent a single code point (≈logical character) (some more details [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44995008/214671)). In particular, б is represented as a string of *two* bytes, namely byte 0xD0 and 0xB1.

C knows nothing about UTF-8 or code points; if you specify `%c` to `scanf`, it reads in a single byte, regardless of the fact that it suffices or not to represent a full UTF-8 code point. So, only the first of those bytes got read, and `c` just contains the 0xD0 value; the 0xB1 is still in the buffer, yet to be read.

Coming back to the value displayed by the debugger, first of all it must be noted that on your platform (as, unfortunately, on many platforms), `char` is signed. Hence, the 0xD0 byte is interpreted as a signed value as -48 (indeed, 0xD0 = 208, which "wraps around" at 127; 208 - 256 = -48).

As for `'\320'`: the debugger here would like to display the ASCII representation of that value; however, the byte 0xD0 is outside the ASCII character range<sup>2</sup>, so here it gets displayed with an escape sequence. You may be familiar with `'\n'` to represent the newline character or `\0` for the NUL character; in general, a `\` followed by one to three digits in C means the byte with the corresponding *octal* value; `0320` is indeed octal for 208, which is decimal for 0xD0.

So, no mystery here: `c` still contains a single value (which is just "half" of your character); what you are seeing are just two (equally inconvenient) representations of its content.

---

***Notes***

1. On most platforms, [-128, 127] or [0, 255], depending on the signedness of `char` (which, unfortunately, is implementation-defined).
2. Indeed, UTF-8 *extends* ASCII by using only bytes with the high bit set (unused by ASCII) for its multibyte sequences; this makes sure that they cannot be misinterpreted for ASCII text.

Answer (score 3):

Cyrillic characters [using `utf-8`] are *multibyte* `char`s. Your "character" in hex is the string/array:

```
D0B1
```

So, you *can't* use `%c` to retrieve it. You need to use `%s`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int
main(void)
{
    char utf[1000];
    char *cp;

    scanf("%s", utf);
    printf("%s\n", utf);

    for (cp = utf;  *cp != 0;  ++cp)
        printf(" %2.2X",*cp & 0xFF);
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

---

Here is the output:

```
б
 D0 B1
```

---

**UPDATE:**

> So, how does that char is located in memory? Is C able to make char 2-byte when it comes to cyrillic?

First and foremost, see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8

When you enter a cyrillic character via your keyboard, it is a combination of your keyboard hardware, terminal emulator program, and text editor that convert the keyboard sequence into the `utf-8` sequence which ends up in the text file you're editing.

What you're calling a cyrillic character is what `utf-8` calls a "code point".

When placed in a text file, the code point becomes a multibyte sequence as mentioned above.

`scanf` and `printf` have no knowledge of this. For example, `printf` just sends out the string: `XXXXXXX\0` where X can be a single ASCII char or part of a multichar code point.

It is up to the terminal emulator to make sense of this and output the correct character from the utf-8 font set [which contains cyrillic chars, greek chars, french chars, etc.]

Functions such as `strlen` and `strcpy` *only* care about the trailing 0x00 EOS char. So, technically, they work and can usually pass through a `utf-8` string just as easily as an ASCII one as the EOS is the same regardless.

But, `strlen` will give you the number of `char` in the string. For example, in the above `strlen` will return 2 because it counts `D0` and `B1` as separate `char` values in a `char` array.

And, `strchr` [probably] would not work. You'd probably want to use `strstr` in its place for `utf-8`.

Of course, there is only *one* code point for the cyrillic character in it, so `utf-8` aware functions have to process the array differently. For example, when counting the number of code points, they need to see that `D0B1` is a *single* code point, so the resulting count is *one*

The general rule is that ASCII (`0x01-0x7F`) maps directly onto `utf-8` as single `char`s. Anything that has the high bit (`0x80`) set is part of a `utf-8` multibyte code point. The `0x40` is used to indicate the *start* [leftmost] byte of the sequence. All remaining bytes in the sequence are of the form (in bits): `10xxxxxx`. The number of remaining bytes in the sequence is denoted by the number of prefix 1 bits in the start byte. In the table below, it shows how to decode the byte sequence (`x` denotes a bit that is part of code point value):

```
# of    Start       Remaining Bytes
bytes   Byte
1       0xxxxxxx
2       110xxxxx    10xxxxxx
3       1110xxxx    10xxxxxx    10xxxxxx
4       11110xxx    10xxxxxx    10xxxxxx    10xxxxxx
```

Thus, a `utf-8` aware function can detect and skip over code points when scanning in either a forward or reverse direction. And, can distinguish between two [or more] adjacent multibyte code points.

Comment: So, how does that char is located in memory? Is C able to make char 2-byte when it comes to cyrillic?
Does that mean that i can assign to `char c` cyrillic б? Allthough it's one byte?

Comment: Well I actually just understood how `scanf("%c")` actually worked, it took one byte from cyrillic **б**, which is actually two-byte. But what is `/320` then?